# Why "Get Suites By Test Case Id" REST call returns "The request is invalid"?

Tags: rest, tfs, azure-devops-rest-api, azure-devops-server-2019

I am trying to retrieve all test suits which contain a specific test case by test case ID.

I'm sending the following GET call:

```
GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{DefaultCollection/}_apis/test/suites?testCaseId={testCaseId}&api-version=5.0
```

Instead of receiving the list of test suits I get the following response:

```
{"count":1,"value":{"Message":"The request is invalid."}}
```

If I add project to the request url, I get `Page not found 404` error, so I assume, project name should not be there. But even without it I get `request is invalid` message.

Test Case ID is correct, I've tried several, and the response was the same.

What am I missing with this REST call? I didn't have similar issues with other calls.

I used the following Microsoft resource for reference:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/test/test%20%20suites/get%20suites%20by%20test%20case%20id?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0

Comment: Do you use Azure DevOps or TFS?

Comment: We have Azure DevOps in organization.

Comment: So remove the {DefeaultCollection} from the GET call.

Comment: Without DefaultCollection I receive "The page you are looking for is currently unavailable"

Comment: Can you share exactly the URL you tried?

Comment: https://{organization name}/{default collection}/_apis/test/suites?testCaseId={test case ID}&api-version=5.0

Comment: You need `https://dev.azure.com/{organiztion}`....

Comment: We have an internal server. And other REST calls work perfectly well.

Comment: can you share the url when you enter a project? (replace the real values)

Comment: If you have an internal server is NOT Azure DevOps, it's TFS (or Azure DevOps **Server**). do you know which version do you have?

Comment: We have Azure DevOps Server 2019

Comment: Other API with version=5.0 are working?

Comment: Yes. Other commands with this version are working.

Comment: Try to remove the `&api-vesrion=5.0`

Comment: Yes. Deleting everything after test case ID solved it. You can post it a solution. Thanks.

Comment: Great! I posted is as a solution. I guess it also works with `api-version=4.0`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably Azure DevOps Server 2019 not support in `api-version-5.0` in this API call, so just need to remove it (then the call did with the default correct version):

```
http://azure-devops-server:8080/tfs/collection/_apis/test/suites?testCaseId=1
```